# MQL4 - How to hide some segments of an Indicator line?

Tags: mql4

I'm making a custom indicator.
I want to show theoretical brake out lines. So like, straight horizontal line segments. At the moment I have it working, using the semantics of **`DRAW_SECTION`**, except - obviously - all my segments are connected.

Is there a way to hide sections of the line that I don't need?
Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Two scenarios:

## 1.

`SetIndexStyle( i, DRAW_NONE );` where `i` is the number of your buffer.

## 2.

`#property indicator_buffers 3`
`IndicatorBuffers(4);`
where
`3` is a number of buffers to display,
`4` is a  total number of buffers. Even though you cannot see the buffer line on the chart, it is still accessed by `iCustom( _Symbol, 0, indicator_name, ..., 3, shift );`
where `3` is a zero-based reference to the buffer #4.

Comment: It seems like this hides the entire line? I just want to hide sections of it.

Comment: If you want to hide part of the buffer (e.g. all except last 100 bars) - you have to reassign to zero or split between two arrays, one for hided elements and other, another for drawing. But that wont work faster so it doesnt make much sence

Answer (score 0):

### There is a way in MQL4 Indicators :

As documented, there is a special value **`== EMPTY_VALUE`** to serve exactly this purpose.

> The **`EMPTY_VALUE`** constant usually corresponds to the values of indicators **that are not shown** in the chart.

Just assign, where plausible in your indicator code - either per-bar in assignment **`BreakOutBUFFER[i] = ( isHereBreakOut( i ) ) ? aLevel : EMPTY_VALUE;`**
or
by a pre-initialised `ArrayInitialize( BreakOutBUFFER, EMPTY_VALUE );` and re-assigning only those cells, where your BreakOut-logic is POSACK'd, yet this is not a preferred way, as the first sooner-or-later coming ( automatic or not ) `ArrayResize()` will extend this Buffer, as documented:

> *... the elements will be added at the end of the array, their values will be undefined and in most cases will not be equal to init_value.*

but .... **not** with the pre-set `EMPTY_VALUE` initialiser...

---

My option is, obviously, to go the former way